# Angular[karma] Async testing on Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I try to test an async case.
My component:

```
  ngOnInit(private service: MyService) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.service.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

As you can see i set loading to true and when the data have been checked isLoading become false.
This is what i want to test.
I tried with tick(), whenStable...
I spy MyService to return an Observable with mockData, but i can't catch isLoading to true.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
it('should ...', done => {
  const dataMock = {};
  spyOn(component['service'], 'getData').and.returnValue(of(dataMock);
  component['service'].getData().pipe(delay(500)).subscribe(data => {
    expect(component.data).toBe(dataMock));
    expect(component.isLoading).toBeFalsy();
    done();
  });

  expect(component.isLoading).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: I have no problem to test isLoading to false or component.data.
What i wouild like to test is isLoading to true, (before service subscribe)

Comment: Thanks, working well, i tried with timeout instead of delay, but not working.

Comment: Timeout definition is `Error if no value is emitted before specified duration`. Delay is the one you want !